# get initials from string of words

Tags: r

What I have:

```
names <- c("First Last", "First M Last", "First M. Last", "first Last", "first lAst")
```

What I want:

```
"FL" "FML" "FML" "FL" "FL"
```

What I tried:

```
paste(substr(strsplit(names, " ")[[1]], 1, 1), collapse="")
```

What this gives:

```
FL
```

How can I get this for all elements?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
> names <- c("First Last", "First M Last", "First M. Last", 
             "first Last", "first lAst")
```

It looks like you want the result to be all upper case? If that's the case, we can use `toupper` inside `sapply` with similar code to what you've tried.

```
> s <- strsplit(names, " ")
> sapply(s, function(x){
      toupper(paste(substring(x, 1, 1), collapse = ""))
  })
# [1] "FL"  "FML" "FML" "FL"  "FL"
```

Comment: That would work for my example. I should have added a case like "first Last", however, to reflect my real use case.

Comment: So essentially you just want the first letter of each word?

Answer (score 1):

If you run your own logic over each element you get the desired results:

```
sapply( names, function(x)
                  paste(substr(strsplit(x, " ")[[1]], 1, 1), collapse="") )
```

If you do not like the names You can `unname` the result:

```
> unname(sapply( names, function(x)
+ paste(substr(strsplit(x, " ")[[1]], 1, 1), collapse="") ))
[1] "FL"  "FML" "FML" "fL"  "fl"
```

Or use the USE.NAMES parameter:

```
> sapply( names, function(x)
+ paste(substr(strsplit(x, " ")[[1]], 1, 1), collapse="") , USE.NAMES=FALSE)
[1] "FL"  "FML" "FML" "fL"  "fl"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another option using regular expressions:

```
# find letters preceded by a space (\\s) or the beginning of the string (^)
regex <- '(?<=^|\\s)[[:alpha:]]' 
initials <- regmatches(names, gregexpr(regex, names, perl=TRUE))
toupper(sapply(initials, paste0, collapse=''))
# [1] "FL"  "FML" "FML" "FL"  "FL"
```